# How I convert a BSON Document into a map[string]interface{}

Tags: mongodb, go, mongo-go

I was trying to decode the data of the cursor into a map[string]interface{}, I tried it directly but it doesn't works at all, so I fount that I have to convert  it to a BSON document and next convert it to a map[string]interface{}, and finally into a JSON string. I tried the following code:

```
...
for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
    err = cursor.Decode(&itemBson)
    ...
    b, err := bson.Marshal(itemBson)
    ...
    err = bson.Unmarshal(b, &itemMap)
    ...
}
...
```

But the bson document has the following value:

map[_id:ObjectID("5c2d0809a49bad7d547ec028") applications:bson.Array[bson.Document{bson.Element{"enabled": true}}] userName:coto userUUID:df2d
ea92-c189-53b3-aafe-485d0be23bee]

And the map parsed as JSON:

{"_id":"5c2d0809a49bad7d547ec028","applications":[{}],"userName":"coto","userUUID":"df2dea92-c189-53b3-aafe-485d0be23bee"}

As you can see the key "applications" is empty in the JSON, but it really has content in the BSON document. I don't know why the data disappear.

How I can solve this error?
Thanks.

Comment: Show the type definition for `itemBson`.  You should be able to decode to map[string]interface{} directly. What happens when you do? Is there an error or is the value not what you expect.

Comment: @Marco could you provide a working example?

Comment: @Marco Did you find any better way for this? I think there is a solution with bsoncodec.Registery

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Solved:**

I solved this error using the following code:

```
var jsonDocuments []map[string]interface{}
var byteDocuments []byte

var bsonDocument bson.D
var jsonDocument map[string]interface{}
var temporaryBytes []byte

for cursor.Next(context.Background()) {
    err = cursor.Decode(&bsonDocument)

    ...

    temporaryBytes, err = bson.MarshalExtJSON(bsonDocument, true, true)

    ...

    err = json.Unmarshal(temporaryBytes, &jsonDocument)

    ...

    jsonDocuments = append(jsonDocuments, jsonDocument)
}
```

Comment: Which version of mongo-go-driver did you use?

Comment: v0.0.19-prerelease @simagix

Comment: Figured, saw you used `MarshalExtJSON` earlier today.  I couldn't tell from your original post which didn't have details.  My answer was based on the beta version.  The beta is more mgo-like.

Comment: @simagix Yeah, in the next time I'll add more details in my questions. Sorry, my bad. Anyway thanks for helping me!

Comment: It seems like a heavy operation.

Answer (score 5):

```
temp := itemBson.data.(primitive.D) // convert interface to primitive D

metadata := temp.Map() // map to map[string]interface{}

if v, ok := metadata[prqKey]; ok { // check and use value
    commitID = v.(string)
}
```

You can use the built-in interface on the `primitive.D` type to convert it to a `map[string]interface{}`